# How to solve: "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Timeout was reached: "?

Tags: r, web-scraping, try-catch

I'm running a script and I need it to try for a few more seconds to collect the data, but if it still can not, I need it to assign NA in the dataframe and return to me the links that did not work.
I'm using a loop for to generate a dataframe.

```
LINKS <- LinksBR$LINKS_SP[1:39224]

DataSP <- matrix(nrow = 39244, ncol = 2)

DataSP <- data.frame(DataSP)

for (i in 1:length(LINKS)){
  try(
    DataSP[i,1] <- read_html(LINKS[i]) %>%
      html_node(".blabla > h1") %>%
      html_text()
  )
  try(
    Data[i,2] <- read_html(LINKS[i]) %>%
      html_node(".blabla") %>%
      html_text("span")
  )

}

Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
  Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10015 milliseconds
```

Comment: Welcome! So, if the script just tries for a few more seconds that will solve your problem (and if it fails just use an `NA`)?

Comment: Thank you!@Hack-R
Yes, my problem will be solve if the script tries for a few more seconds and if it fails use NA. With this I can make the list of thoose who did not work.